# requirejs/r.js node ./bin/r.js when build -o xxx.js got ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js

I know there was a little similar questions, but there is no clear solution for this issue. Please for hint how to fix problem with using node modules on windows 7 x64. I read that there is problem with execution scripts from node modules on windows. I read about DOSkeys, but it is not clear solution. Please do not say to change operation system for linux also, because I really think about that (<_<')

When I try

```
node node_modules/.bin/r.js -o build.js
```

Got that:

```
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:4
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Thanks for all clues.

Comment: Please do not incorporate solutions into the body of your question. This goes against SO editorial customs. People who find your question and are looking for an answer should follow the link that was added at the top of your question when it was closed as a duplicate. This is really the better thing to do for them because someone in the future could post a better answer than what you saw or the answer that you are using now could become obsolete when a new version is released.

Answer (score -1):

This character ` is a [Grave Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent). You can't use it in code. Replace it with a straight single quote as seen below:

```
'
```

It is possible that the encoding was incorrect. They can get munged from version control, or switching between platforms, or some sort of pre-compiler action.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. But only one basedir statement I got in npm, but with changing this value from ` to ' , it gives no result.

Also, when I try to run it via r.js.cmd I got this:
"
$ r.js.cmd
/c/Users/Uland/AppData/Roaming/npm/r.js.cmd: line 1: syntax error near unexpecte
d token `('
/c/Users/Uland/AppData/Roaming/npm/r.js.cmd: line 1: `@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe"
 ('
"
Inside r.js.cmd we have:

@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js" %*
)

Comment: Resolved:

Like in thread suggested by Louis, on win7 we need to make global instalation of requirejs, make doskey (just enter in cmd) 

DOSKEY r.js=r.js.cmd $*

After that we use global command (without node on front) 

r.js -o yourbuild.js

and no basedir problem.